# Javascript - Value not passing to function

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

So I have this form:

```
<form name="login" id="login" action="" method="POST" onSubmit="return test()">
        <input type="text" size="10" name="username" /><div id="wrongUser"></div>
            <br />
        <input type="password" size="10" name="password" /><div id="wrongPass"></div>
            <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /><br /><br />
</form>
```

and these two functions:

```
function test()
{
    var user = document.login.username.value;
    var pass = document.login.password.value;
    if((user == "" || user == null) && (pass == "" || pass == null))
    {
        document.getElementById('wrongUser').innerText = "Please Enter Username";
        document.getElementById('wrongPass').innerText = "Please Enter Password";
        return false;
    }

    if(checkEmpty(user, 'wrongUser', "Please Enter Username"))
        return false

    if(checkEmpty(pass, 'wrongPass', "Please Enter Password"))
        return false;

    return true;
}

function checkEmpty(name, id, output)
{
    if(name == "" || name == null)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).innerText = "";
        document.getElementById(id).innerText = output;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now the functions kinda work but not how I would think. If the user only doesn't enter anything (first time) then they get the 2 errors. If the user enter just a username (second time) then the username error should disappear, but it doesn't. If I take it out of the function and replace the variables with their normal values then it works just fine. Why would it change when put in this function?

Comment: As an aside, innerText is an IE-only property - I would check if textContent is supported and use that first (all browsers support it except IE < 9), then fall back to innerText.

Comment: Huh so it is. Works in latest version of Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `document.getElementById().innerText = ''` in the else, not in the if. Because you only reset the innerText when it's empty, but you would like to reset the tekst if it's not empty:

```
function checkEmpty( name, id, output ) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id); // it's faster to put the element in a var

  if( name === undefined || name == '' name == null )
    elem.innerText = output;
    return true;
  else
    elem.innerText = '';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ahh gotcha. I put it in my `innerText=''` in my else and it works for username but not password?